# How can i set the attribute of an element in MVC

Tags: javascript, jquery, dom, setattribute

my view:

<........id="S" labelPos="1" labelText=""/>

I want to set the value for labelText dynalically from the controller. i have tried the following but it did not work:

```
                for (var i = 0; i < keys.length; i++) {
                    var c = labelText[keys[i]].StreetName;
                    var d = document.getElementsByTagName("S");
                    d.setAttribute("labelText", c);

                }
```

Comment: What is `keys` ? What is `labelText` ? What does it contain ?

Comment: the issue is it doesnt know what d is

Comment: labelText is the attribute name what i want is "labelText" = "the value of c"

Comment: c is just a string e.g c= "hello" only the code from where i set var d is not working

Comment: `getElementsByTagName` returns a _collection_. You should _iterate_ through the collection or get a specific element from the collection by index and then use the `setAttribute` function. However, it seems you don't need the `getElementsByTagName` here. Do you really have a `<S>` element? What you need is `.getElementById`.

Comment: This is the second vague question that I have seen from you. Please read [How to create a Minimal, Complete, and Verifiable example](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve) before asking another question.

Comment: What do you mean by "in MVC"? Are you talking about ASP.NET MVC? Because the tag for that is `asp.net-mvc`, not `model-view-controller`. It is also redundant if all you're doing is updating things in JavaScript.

Answer (score 0):

Please change your `document.getElementsByTagName("S");`to `document.getElementById("S")` see if it works.

```
               for (var i = 0; i < keys.length; i++) {
                    var c = labelText[keys[i]].StreetName;
                    var d = document.getElementById("S");
                    d.setAttribute("labelText", c);

                }
```

Comment: This is correct, but the loop will reset the attribute in each iteration! The code is logically broken.

Answer (score 0):

First query your elements in DOM, querying in loop is not good practice, so:

```
var elements = document.getElementsByTagName("span");//span is example element
```

Or:

```
var elements = document.quertSelectorAll("selector");//your elements by selector
```

Use it in loop

```
for (var i = 0; i < elements.length; i++) {


     elements[i].setAttribute("labelText", labelText[elements[i].getAttribute("labelPos")].StreetName);

}
```

I came to the conclusion that Your **labelPos** attribute is index of **labelText** array, this would be logical. So in above code I set attrbute from **labelText** array by **labelPos** value as key.

Second possibility if DOM elements are in the same order as labelText array:

```
for (var i = 0; i < elements.length; i++) {

     //we take i element in DOM and set it StreetName from i element in labelText array
     elements[i].setAttribute("labelText", labelText[i].StreetName);

}
```

Comment: labelPos is not related to this. is there a way of doing it without using labelpos?

Comment: I updated my answer, this will work if order is the same.

Comment: how can i do this for each of the streetName inside an array. i will need 2 nested for loops. one to get the element and one to set attribute for each item in the array

Comment: Please provide Your data structure and html structure then i will try help